# Assigning physics bodies to multiple objects in a custom sprite node class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where I use the scene editor to lay out trees. I want to create a custom `Spritenode` class that assigns the correct physics to all of the trees. When I write the physics, it only applies to one of the trees. I am setting all of the trees as children of the Tree class.

```
class Tree: SKSpriteNode {

    func setTreePhysics(){
                self.zPosition = 6
                self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
                self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.tree
                self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player
                self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

            }
}
```

I would expect these physics to apply to all of the trees that are children of the class. I did a similar thing for my player class and it worked fine.

Comment: If you have actually modeled your `tree` class on your `player` class then it should behave the same. Are you definitely calling `setTreePhysics` for each tree? (P.S> don't say 'children' as that has a specific meaning in SpriteKit - they are 'instances' of that class).

Comment: If you are using scene builder, then use scene builder to create your physics body

Comment: I guess my issue is I am not calling the setTreePhysics for each tree I have assigned the class to. I am not sure how to call it for each tree in that scene I have made in instance of the class. Also, I could use the scene builder to create the physics body, however I prefer writing it out in code. I find it easier to apply Bitmasks and stuff through code.

Comment: ... if code was easier, you would not be here on SO asking this question.  The reason you want to do it in the scene builder is because it is unnecessary code fluff that could be a code smell (like in your case)  Take out the fluff, and you have less opportunities for your code to be infected with a bug.

Comment: @kyfi13 You could create the physics bodies in Scene Builder and the category/collision/contactTest bit makss in code. It does make sense to create the nodes and their physics bodies in the same place...

Comment: @kyfi13 If you still want to create the physics body in your code, yet place the nodes in Scene Builder, then you will have to iterate over every node (via `enumeratechildNodes`) and call `setTreePhysics` on each node.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I am a high schooler just beginning to learn SpriteKit so all of the help is greatly appreciated!